# Sniffing the "Print Screen" key to attach its' contents on a composed mail automatically

Tags: javascript, php, email, dom-events

How can I sniff the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key so that when it is pressed, a number of events happen on a web page:

1. There will be a dialog box that will pop up so that the user will only have to input the email address of the recipient.
2. The image on the clipboard is automatically attached to the composed mail.

If it helps, I'm using PHP 5.3.5, Javascript and Swift mailer.

Answer (score 5):

This is *completely* impossible.

Comment: Even with a signed Java applet?  You sure?  The user would have to trust it, but given the right circumstances that might not be a problem.

Comment: @tva: That's cheating.  Besides, _in the background_?  Can it catch unfocused keystrokes and check the active **tab**?

Comment: @SLaks - hmm, I suppose but perhaps you could get close.  Perhaps a two-step process of using Print Screen then click a Send Clipboard button?  Or maybe it's not a problem if it only works when the web page is focused (keypress handler on the body element?).

Comment: @tva: I highly doubt that you can do that in an applet.

Comment: @SLaks - I've got an applet (signed, of course) that's able to read network information from the client.  I call it from javascript to pass back the IP addresses, MAC address, and computer name in my WoL registration app.  Seems reasonably likely that you'd be able to get at the clipboard as well, though I haven't tried.

Comment: @tva: Yes; you probably can, but I don't think you'll be able to catch the Print Screen key.  Either way, this discussion is rather pointless. :)

Comment: What if another language like C/C++ provides the data input to javascript?

Comment: @Jiego: It will be **extremely** difficult to properly catch the PrintScreen key.  Also, then you don't need Javascript anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I heard that the function can be solved using Delphi, but that's just Delphi alone. now how can this be solved using Delphi, Javascript and PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get access using a signed Java applet.  I do that to read some network properties for a web-based Wake-On-Lan service, but I've never tried to access the system clipboard.  I suspect that there's probably a better way to do what you're trying but you don't give any information on the actual application to make a suggestion.

Comment: The application is to send an email with an attachment. And that attachment is the image found on the clipboard inputted by the Print Screen key.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access clipboard and other system-specific facilities with javascript, due to security. Let alone sniff the keyboard.

Comment: You can actually "sniff" a lot of things on the keyboard using the keypress/up/down events in Javascript, but you can't sniff the Print Screen button.

Comment: Actually sniffing the keyboard is the easier part.

Comment: only if there's focus on the element.

Comment: @Jakub sniffing is registering global handler for keyboard, Keypress events on an object is not sniffing.